# How to fix dragged movement in touchDragged?

Tags: libgdx

I'm creating a [jigsaw puzzle game](https://github.com/Slideshow776/Kotlin-Game-Development-with-LibGDX/tree/master/chapter9/jigsawPuzzle) where you can drag and drop puzzle pieces.
I wanted to add rotation by increments of 90 degrees on a double-tap. When moving a rotated puzzle piece, weird movement upon dragging occurs.

e.g. After rotating it clock-wise 90 degrees, and then moving it the puzzle piece will not follow the mouse and instead rotates on an outwards spiral on any mouse movement.

Each rotation has its own weird movement, but when rotated 360 degrees the movement is o.k again.

Why is this?

It seems like the listeners x and y input is causing the problem. `public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)`

I think when rotating an actor something else also needs to be done as well, but I can't figure out what...

The puzzle piece actor which inherits Group and has it's own overridden listener.

```
override fun doubleTap() {
        super.doubleTap()
        /*addAction(Actions.rotateBy(-90f, .25f))*/
        rotateBy(-90f)
    }
```

I expect the puzzle piece to always follow the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
Apparently when rotating Actors its coordinate system rotates with it.

I solved the problem with this code:

```
override fun touchDragged(event: InputEvent?, eventOffsetX: Float, eventOffsetY: Float, pointer: Int) {
    val cos = cos(self.rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians)
    val sin = sin(self.rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians)

    val tox = (eventOffsetX - self.grabOffsetX)
    val toy = (eventOffsetY - self.grabOffsetY)

    var deltaX = 0f
    var deltaY = 0f

    if (abs(cos) == 1f) {
        deltaX = tox * cos
        deltaY = toy * cos
    } else {
        deltaX = toy * -sin
        deltaY = tox * sin
    }

    self.moveBy(deltaX, deltaY)
}
```

If anyone have an explanation I would love to hear it.

Comment: Since actors are rotated by 90 degrees I'm not sure my algorithm would work on smaller increments. A more optimal solution might still exist.